# error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c, pointers

I have a C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int b = 10;             //assign the integer 10 to variable 'b'

  int *a;                 //declare a pointer to an integer 'a'

  a=(int *)&b;            //Get the memory location of variable 'b' cast it
                          //to an int pointer and assign it to pointer 'a'

  int *c;                 //declare a pointer to an integer 'c'

  c=(int *)&a;            //Get the memory location of variable 'a' which is
                          //a pointer to 'b'.  Cast that to an int pointer 
                          //and assign it to pointer 'c'.

  printf("%d",(**c));     //ERROR HAPPENS HERE.  

  return 0;
}
```

Compiler produces an error:

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
```

Can someone explain what this error means?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since `c` is holding the address of an integer pointer, its type should be `int**`:

```
int **c;
c = &a;
```

The entire program becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
int main(){
    int b=10;
    int *a;
    a=&b;
    int **c;
    c=&a;
    printf("%d",(**c));   //successfully prints 10
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also note the lack of casts in the answer. The casts in the question hide the problems on the line that is assigning an `int **` to a `int *`. (`c=(int *)&a;`)

Answer (score 18):

**Barebones C program to produce the above error:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char *p;
    *p = 'c';

    cout << *p[0];  
    //error: invalid type argument of `unary *'
    //peeking too deeply into p, that's a paddlin.

    cout << **p;    
    //error: invalid type argument of `unary *'
    //peeking too deeply into p, you better believe that's a paddlin.
}
```

ELI5:

The master puts a shiny round stone inside a small box and gives it to a student.  The master says: "Open the box and remove the stone".  The student does so.

Then the master says: "Now open the stone and remove the stone".  The student said: "I can't open a stone".

The student was then enlightened.

Answer (score 5):

I have reformatted your code.

The error was situated in this line :

```
printf("%d", (**c));
```

To fix it, change to :

```
printf("%d", (*c));
```

The * retrieves the value from an address. The ** retrieves the value (an address in this case) of an other value from an address.

In addition, the () was optional.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b = 10; 
    int *a = NULL;
    int *c = NULL;

    a = &b;
    c = &a;

    printf("%d", *c);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT :**

The line :

```
c = &a;
```

must be replaced by :

```
c = a;
```

It means that the value of the pointer 'c' equals the value of the pointer 'a'. So, 'c' and 'a' points to the same address ('b'). The output is :

```
10
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to use a double * :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b = 10; 
    int *a = NULL;
    int **c = NULL;

    a = &b;
    c = &a;

    printf("%d", **c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: I am not sure that solves the problem, the printed result is "-108149370" and not 10.

Comment: yes Sandro that does print 10 then, but the objective is to use double dereference to print the value of b (i.e. 10).

Comment: I think the **c was intentional.

Comment: @picstand see my EDIT 2 ;) is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare the type of a variable, you don't need to cast it to that same type. So you can write `a=&b;`.  Finally, you declared `c` incorrectly. Since you assign it to be the address of `a`, where `a` is a pointer to `int`, you must declare it to be a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int b=10;
    int *a=&b;
    int **c=&a;
    printf("%d", **c);
    return 0;
}
```