# C : Working with structures and pointers , error : invalid type argument of unary ‘*’

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working on a c program and here is the structure I am using

```
struct EngineParts{

    int serial_number;
    unsigned int year_of_manufacture;
    unsigned int quantity;
    char *material;

}*Eparts;
```

And I am getting the following error

```
`Automobile.c:79:5: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘unsigned int’)` 

`Automobile.c:80:5: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)` 

`Automobile.c:81:5: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘unsigned int’)`
```

in these three lines

```
 *new->quantity = quantity;
 *new->serial_number = serial_number;
 *new->year_of_manufacture = year_of_manufacture;
```

Here is the complete implementation

```
void automobile_add_part(const int serial_number,
        const unsigned int year_of_manufacture,
        const unsigned int quantity , 
        const char *material){
    /*
     * Store the address to the latest part
     */
   struct EngineParts *new ;
   new = (Eparts+available_number_of_parts);

    // Copying a String is a little bit complicated
    // First memory is allocated for the string 
    *new->material = (char *)calloc(strlen(material),sizeof(char));
    //Then the string is copied
    strcpy((char *)*new->material,material);    

    *new->quantity = quantity;
    *new->serial_number = serial_number;
    *new->year_of_manufacture = year_of_manufacture;

    available_number_of_parts++;
}
```

PS : 
I have checked out the following questions ,

[error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455866/error-invalid-type-argument-of-unary-have-int)

[Invalid type argument of -> C structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983010/invalid-type-argument-of-c-structs)

but they don't seem to help me.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
new->quantity = quantity;
```

The extra pointer dereference (`*new->quantity`) is an error: `new->quantity` is an `int`, not any kind of pointer so the compiler complains.

Dereferencing the `new` pointer (is it even legal to have a variable named such?) is already done through `operator->`.

Comment: It is legal C to have a variable named `new`. The `new` operator is an C++'ism.

Comment: since I am using pure c I think I can get away with using new as a variable name .

Answer (score 6):

The `->` operator already dereferences the pointer for you.

`new->serial_number` is equivalent to `(*new).serial_number`, both of which seem like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator dereferences the pointer, so use of additional `*` is not required. And results in error.

Answer (score 1):

no need `*` for `new->quantity`

the `->` is shortcut for `(*new).quantity`