# Modifying a struct passed as a pointer - C

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm trying to modify a struct that was passed as a parameter by using a pointer by I can't get it working. I cant just return the struct because the function must return an integer. How can I modify the struct in the function? This is what I've done so far:

```
typedef enum {TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3} types;

typedef struct {
                types type;
                int act_quantity;
                int reorder_threshold;
                char note[100];

}elem;

int update_article(elem *article, int sold)
{
    if(*article.act_quantity >= sold)
    {
        article.act_quantity = article.act_quantity - sold;
        if(article.act_quantity < article.act_quantity)
        {
            strcpy(article.note, "to reorder");
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else if(article.act_quantity < venduto)
    {
        strcpy(*article.note, "act_quantity insufficient");
        return -2;
    }


}
```

I get this error: "error: request for member: 'act_quantity' in something not a structure or union' " in all the lines where I tried to modify the struct.

EDIT: I had used "." instead of "->". I fixed it now. It still gives me an error: " invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')"

Comment: Read about `->` operator.

Comment: Hey did u sort out your invalid type argument error? Check in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455866/error-invalid-type-argument-of-unary-have-int) for any similar mistake. Incase its still not sorted out point out the line. Maybe I can help. And I assume the code in your question is the old one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) causes

```
*article.act_quantity
```

to be interpreted as `*(article.act_quantity)`

It should be `(*article).act_quantity` or `article->act_quantity` (when the LHS is a pointer)

Comment: @Arlind Seriously, use the arrow (`->`) syntax, it's much easier.

Answer (score 6):

When you reference a pointer to a structure you need either

```
article->act_quantity
```

or

```
(*article).act_quantity
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `ptr->member`, not a `ptr.member` when dealing with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Change `*article.act_quantity` to `(*article).act_quantity`, or better to `article->act_quantity`, etc. Operator precedence gets you here ...

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the problem

```
int update_article(elem *article, int sold)
{
    if(article->act_quantity >= sold)
    {
        article->act_quantity = article->act_quantity - sold;
        if(article->act_quantity < article->reorder_threshold)
        {
            strcpy(article->note, "to reorder");
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else if(article->act_quantity < sold)
    {
        strcpy( article->note, "act_quantity insufficient");
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return a pointer to the struct because it will still remain the same as the input. You pass address to the function and you work with something that is at this address. No need to return anything connected with the struct in this case

`article` is a pointer therefore You can't just use `article.act_quantity` and You should replace `.` with `->`

`article->act_quantity`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow operators to access members of a  structure using structure pointer. But valid memory must be there.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
strcpy(*article.note, "act_quantity insufficient");
```

won't work, `note` is a character array, you can't derference it. You need:

```
strcpy(article->note, "act_quantity insufficient");
```

Answer (score 0):

- It still gives me an error: " invalid type argument of unary '*'
  (have 'int')"

Because you write `*article->act_quantity` instead of `article->act_quantity`. Fix it

Answer (score 0):

it is only a matter of precedence. In C, the '*' operator has less precedence than the dot '.' operator, but parentheses () have the highest precedence in C. Thus you need to add parentheses the following way `(*article).act_quantity`.

Comment: What does this add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16841064/10871073), posted over 10 years ago?

Comment: May be more enlightening for someone. It happens to me that sometimes going through multiple slightly different answers for a given question enlightens me and makes it click.