# Pointers and struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my problem...i've got this code(creating a list)

```
typedef struct node
{
    int pid;
    int runtime;
    struct node *next;
}job;

int main()
//code
job *first = NULL;
job *last = NULL;
job *newnode;
//code
//from here
if( first == NULL )
{
     first = last = newnode;
     newnode->next = NULL;
}
else
{
     last->next = newnode;
     last = last->next;
}
// to here
```

So i wanted to do the part between from here to here in a function(so it would look better)
And i did this..i created a function

```
void funct(job ** pfirst, job **plast, job*newnode);
```

in main instead of the strong part i use:

```
 funct(&first, &last, newnode);
```

and the function was like this

```
void funct(job ** pfirst, job **plast, job*newnode)
{
   if(*pfirst == NULL)
   {
      *pfirst = *plast = newnode;
       newnode->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      *plast->next = newnode;//<----
      *plast = *plast->next;//<----
   }
}
```

The error is in the arrow and sais not part of a struct..

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16841064/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`->` has [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) over `*`(Dereference) operator so you need parenthesis `()` around `list` to overwrite precedence. Correct it like: 
`(*last)->next = newnode;`

`*last->next = newnode;` is wrong because it same as `*(last->next) = newnode;` and `list` has no member `next`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solutions mentioned here your 2nd code has logical error.. you should be checking for `if(*pfirst == NULL)` and not `if(*pfirst != NULL)`

```
void funct(job ** pfirst, job **plast, job*newnode)
{
   if((*pfirst) == NULL)
   {
      *pfirst = *plast = newnode;
       newnode->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      (*plast)->next = newnode;//<----
      *plast = (*plast)->next;//<----
   }
}
```

Also considering you are creating `List` it will be better use (Remember you can do it even without `last` pointer).. this approach makes it easy to create **more than One list** Or **Array Of List**

```
typedef struct node
{
    int pid;
    int runtime;
    struct node *next;
}job;

typedef struct List
{
    job *first = NULL;
    job *last = NULL;
}joblist;
```

and then something like

```
int main()
//code
joblist *list= NULL;
job *newnode;
//code
//from here
if( list== NULL )
{
     list =  malloc(sizeof (*list ));
     list->first =list->last=newnode;
     newnode->next = NULL;
}
else
{
     list->last->next = newnode;
     list->last = list->last->next;
}
```